# What's the difference between a cons cell and a 2-vector?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

In Lisps that have vectors, why are cons cells still necessary? As I understand it, a cons cell is:

- A structure with exactly 2 elements
- Ordered
- Access is O(1)

All these also apply to a 2-vector, though. So what's the difference? Are cons cells just a vestige from before Lisps had vectors? Or are there other differences I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although, physically, conses resemble any other two-element aggregate structure, they are not simply an obsolete form of a 2-vector.

Firstly, all types in Lisp are partitioned into `cons` and `atom`.  Only conses are of type `cons`; everything else is an atom. A vector is an atom!

Conses form the representational basis for nested lists, which of course are used to write code. They have a special printed notation, such that the object produced by `(cons 1 (cons 2 nil))` conveniently prints as `(1 2)` and the object produced by `(cons 1 (cons 2 3))` prints as `(1 2 . 3)`.

The `cons` versus `atom` distinction is important in the syntax, because an expression which satisfies the `consp` test is treated as a *compound form*. Whereas atoms that are not keyword symbols, `t` or `nil` evaluate to themselves.

To get the list itself instead of the value of the compound form, we use `quote`, for which we have a nice shorthand.

It's useful to have a vector type which is free from being entangled into the evaluation semantics this way: whose instances are just self-evaluating atoms.

Cons cells are not a vestige from before Lisps had vectors. Firstly, there was almost no such a time. The Lisp 1 manual from 1960 already describes arrays. Secondly, new dialects since then still have conses.

Objects that have a similar representation are not simply redundant for each other. Type distinctions are important. For instance, we would not consider the following two to be redundant for each other just because they both have three slots:

```
(defstruct name first initial last)

(defstruct bank-transaction account type amount)
```

In the TXR Lisp dialect, I once had it so that the syntactic sugar `a..b` denoted `(cons a b)` for ranges.  But this meant that ranges were `consp`, which was silly due to the ambiguity against lists. I eventually changed it so that `a..b` denotes `(rcons a b)`: a form which constructs a range object, which  prints as `#R(x y)`. (and can be specified that way as a literal). This creates a useful nuance because we can distinguish whether a function argument is a range (`rangep`) or a list (`consp`).  Just like we care whether some object is a `bank-transaction` or `name`. Range objects are represented exactly like conses and allocated from the same heaps; just they have a different type which makes them atoms. If evaluated as forms, they evaluate to themselves.

Basically, we must regard type as if it were an extra slot. A two-element vector really has (at least) three properties, not just two: it has a first element, a second element and a type.  The vector `#(1 1)` differs from the cons cell `(1 . 1)` in that they both have this third aspect, type, which is not the same.

The immutable properties of an object which it shares with all other objects of its kind can still be regarded as "slots". Effectively, all objects have a "type slot". So conses are actually three-property objects having a `car`, `cdr` and `type`:

```
(car '(a . b)) -> A
(cdr '(a . b)) -> B
(type-of '(a . b)) -> CONS
```

Her is a fourth "slot":

```
(class-of '(a . b)) -> #<BUILT-IN-CLASS CONS>
```

We can't look at objects in terms of just their per-instance storage vector allocated on the heap.

---

By the way, the 1960's MacLisp dialect extended the concept of a cons into fixed-size aggregate objects that had more named fields (in addition to `car` and `cdr`): the `cxr`-s. These objects were called "hunks" and are [documented in Kent Pitman's MacLisp manual](http://www.maclisp.info/pitmanual/hunks.html). Hunks do not satisify the predicate `consp`, but `hunkp`; i.e. they are considered atoms. However, they extend the cons notation with multiple dots.

Answer (score 2):

In a typical Common Lisp implementation, a cons cell will be represented as "two machine words" (one for the car pointer, one for the cdr pointer; the fact that it's a cons cell is encoded in the pointer constructed to reference it). However, arrays are more complicated object and unless you have a dedicated "two-element-only vector of type T", you'd end up with an array header, containing type information and size, in addition to the storage needed to store elements (probably hard to squeeze to less than "four machine words").

So while it would be eminently possible to use two-element vectors/arrays as cons cells, there's some efficiency to be had by using a dedicated type, based on the fact that cons cells and lists are so frequently used in existing Lisp code.

Answer (score 1):

On one hand this is an "implementation detail": given vectors, one can implement cons cells (and thus linked lists) using vectors of length 2.

On the other hand this is a fairly important detail: the ANSI Common Lisp standard specifies that the types `vector` and `cons` are disjoint, so, in fact, you *cannot* use the trick to implement an ANSI CL.

Answer (score 1):

I think that their are different data structures, for example java has vector and list classes. One is suitable for random access and lists are more suitable for sequential access. So in any language vectors and list can coexists.

For implementing a Lisp using your approach, I believe that it is posible, it depends on your implementations details but for ANSI Common Lisp there is a convention because there is not a list datatype:

```
CL-USER> (type-of (list 1 2 3))
CONS
```

This is a CONS and the convention says something similar to this (looking at the common lisp hypersec):

> list n. 
>         1. a chain of conses in which the car of each cons is an element of the list, and the cdr of each cons is either the next link in the
>   chain or a terminating atom. See also proper list, dotted list, or
>   circular list. 
>         2. the type that is the union of null and cons.

So if you create a Lisp using vectors instead of cons, it will be not the ANSI CL

so you can create lists "consing" things, nil is a list and there are diferrent types of list that you can create with consing:

normally you create a proper list:

```
(list 1 2 3) = (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 nil)))) = '(1 2 3)
```

when the list does not end with nil it is a dotted list, and a circular list has a reference to itself

So for example if we create a string common lisp, implements it as a simple-array, which is faster for random acces than a list

```
CL-USER> (type-of "this is a string")
(SIMPLE-ARRAY CHARACTER (16))
```

Land of lisp (a great book about common lisp) define cons as the glue for building common lisp, and for processing lists, so of course if you replace cons with other thing similar you will build something similar to common lisp.

Finally a tree of the common lisp sequences types, you can find [here](http://sellout.github.io/media/CL-type-hierarchy.png) the complete

[image]

Comment: Great answer. I just want to add for the curious noobs out there that while `type-of` will give them `'cons` as a result on cons cells/lists, they can use `typep` with `list` too. E.g. `(typep '(1 2 3) 'list)` or `(typep (cons 1 2) 'list)`. `(typep '(1 2 3) 'cons)` and `(typep (cons 1 2) 'cons)` will also give `t`.

Comment: @tsikov typeof *might* give cons, but it give something else, too (e.g., t). There's a lot of flexibility.  Using typep  is often a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

> Are cons cells just a vestige from before Lisps had vectors?

Exactly. `cons`, `car`, `cdr` were the constructor and accessors of the only compound data structure in the first lisp. To differentiate it with the only atomic type symbols one had `atom` that were `T` for symbols but false for `cons`. This was extended to other types in [Lisp 1.5](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/LISP/book/LISP%201.5%20Programmers%20Manual.pdf) including vectors (called arrays, see page 35). Common Lisp were a combination of commercial lisps that all built upon lisp 1.5. Perhaps they would have been different if both types were made from the beginning.

If you were to make a Common Lisp implementation you don't need to have two different ways to make them as long as your implementation works according to the spec. If I remember correctly I think racket actually implements struct with vector and `vector?` is overloaded to be `#f` for the vectors that are indeed representing an object. In CL you could implement `defstruct` the same way and implement `cons` struct and the functions it needs to be compatible with the hyperspec. You might be using vectors when you create `cons` in your favorite implementation without even knowing it.

Historically you still have the old functions so that John McCarthy code still works even 58 years after the first lisp. It didn't need to but it doesn't hurt to have a little legacy in a language that had features modern languages are getting today.

Comment: Lisp 1.5 had arrays.

Comment: @RainerJoswig Indeed, page 35. I'm more an more amazed of the feature set of 1.5.

Answer (score 1):

If you used two-element vectors you would store their size (and type) in *every node* of the list.
This is ridiculously wasteful.

You can get around this wastefulness by introducing a special 2-element vector type whose elements can be anything.

Or in other words: by re-introducing the cons cell.